# Trigger an event while navigating to next record

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I need to set the record source of a particular dropdown in a form based on the current record i.e when I click the next record, the record source should get updated.

But I'm unable to find any event for doing so. This needs to be done without adding any extra/new buttons.

I tried using the "Form Current" event but apparently it gets triggered only once when the form is loaded, and not when I move to the next record within the same form.

Any suggestions?

Sample Code:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

 MsgBox ("hello")

 Dim strSQL As String

 strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW StudentTeachingStatusTbl.ID, StudentTeachingStatusTbl.SuccessStatus FROM StudentTeachingStatusTbl WHERE Active = -1" & _
        "or ID IN (Select SuccessID from StudentTeachingExperiencesTbl where StuId = " & Me.Text2.Value

 If Not IsNull(Me.StudentTeachExp_SubF.Controls("SemesterID")) Then
    strSQL = strSQL & " and SemesterID = " & Me.StudentTeachExp_SubF.Controls("SemesterID").Value
 End If

 strSQL = strSQL & ")"

 Me.StudentTeachExp_SubF.Controls("SuccessID").RowSource = strSQL               
 End Sub
```

Comment: If form has a datasource then when you will press next record button then Form_Current() even will be raised.

Comment: Well I added a dummy MessageBox to check if that happens. The Message gets displayed when the form loads for the first time. When I click the Next Record button and it goes from say record no 1 to record no 2, I don't see the MessageBox being displayed. Nor is my record source updated. Am I missing anything?

Comment: I don't see your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "On Current" event is triggered when the form focuses on a new record.
This does happen when opening a form as a consequence the form having a record on it.

The "On Load" and "On Open" are triggered once when opening the form.

Try adding a MsgBox to your "On Current" event code for testing purposes.

Good Luck.

Comment: Here's my code:Private Sub Form_Current()
     MsgBox ("hello")
          
     Dim strSQL As String
    
     strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW StudentTeachingStatusTbl.ID, StudentTeachingStatusTbl.SuccessStatus FROM StudentTeachingStatusTbl WHERE Active = -1" & _
            "or ID IN (Select SuccessID from StudentTeachingExperiencesTbl where StuId = " & Me.Text2.Value & " and SemesterID = " & Me.StudentTeachExp_SubF.Controls("SemesterID").Value & ")"
     
                             
     Me.StudentTeachExp_SubF.Controls("SuccessID").RowSource = strSQL
                  
End Sub

Comment: I don't see any message box being triggered on Form Current.

Comment: Is the form definitely bound to a record source?  Try making a copy of the form and strip it back to basics leaving just the dropdown ( Combo Box ? ) and the "On Current" event.

Comment: Well the record source for this form is a query say something like: Select * from Students where ID = <current student ID>

Comment: The student ID is a filter from a previous form. Basically there's a form which has a button. When we click that button, it opens this form. And on this form, the current event is getting triggered only once for some reason.

Comment: If you only have one record in the form as that SELECT statement implies then the "On Current" event may only be triggered when opening the form. Can you go to a new/empty record by clicking in the record navigator at the bottom of the form?  If you have "Allow Additions : No" this not possible.

Comment: Looks like there was a confusion from my side. I'm a novice w.r.t MS Access. Actually this form is a "sub form" within the parent form. I was trying to execute the "Form Current" event in the main form. I've updated my code to now handle the sub form "Current" event.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you are changing a sub form record source, so are you changing record on the subform or the main form?

If it's the sub form you need to use the subforms OnChange event, not the parent forms event.

Comment: I was changing the main form event which was the problem. I'm now handling the event in the main form. Thanks for that observation!